# Using Ninject in .NET Core Console App

Tags: .net-core, ninject, azure-webjobs, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to migrate my code from a Webjobs project runing on .NET Framework 4.6.1 to a new .NET Core 2.0 Console project. I'm getting errors some errors here:

```
class Program
{
   // Here I'm getting IKernel is obsolete. Use IKernelConfiguration and IReadOnlyKernel message.
   // Also a message that reads: StandardKerynel is obsolete. Use StandardKernelConfiguration and StandardReadOnlyKernel 
   static readonly IKernel Kernel = new StandardKernel();
   static JobHostConfiguration config;

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsDashboard", "connection");
      Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage", "storage connection");

      BootStrapIoc();

      config = new JobHostConfiguration();

      if (config.IsDevelopment)
      {
          config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
      }

      var host = new JobHost(config);
      host.RunAndBlock();
   }

   private static void BootStrapIoc()
   {
      // Also getting an error here that reads: Argument 1: Cannot convert System.Reflection.Assembly to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule>
      Kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
      config = new JobHostConfiguration
      {
         JobActivator = new BrmJobActivator(Kernel)
      };
   }
}
```

I'm also getting errors in my BrmJobActivator code:

```
public class BrmJobActivator : IJobActivator
{
   private readonly IKernel _container;

   public BrmJobActivator(IKernel container)
   {
       _container = container;
   }

   public T CreateInstance<T>()
   {
       return _container.Get<T>();
   }
}
```

UPDATE:
This is the warning message under NuGet packages in my project after installing Ninject package 3.2.2:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also getting an error here that reads: Argument 1: Cannot convert System.Reflection.Assembly to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

There are some changes in the latest prerelease version of Ninject. Please install the latest stable 3.2.2 version instead.

[image]

I tested your code on my side. After updated the Ninject version to 3.2.2, the code worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I installed version 3.2.2 and it seems to work fine. However, I see a warning under NuGet packages. I took a screen shot and updated the original post with it. The message is warning that this package may not be fully compatible with my project.

Comment: Just to clarify further: the project builds without errors and I don't the errors I was getting before.

Comment: You could just ignore it or modify your code to use the latest version of NInject. You need to implement a Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule. Link below is for your reference. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel

Answer (score 0):

[Ninject **3.3.0**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/3.3.0) was released September 26th 2017 and now targets **.NET Standard 2.0** and thus also runs on .NET Core 2.0. Updating to 3.3.0 will fix the warning.